# Divergence of a radial function

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Is there any proof of the relation

$$\nabla\cdot f(r)= \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}({r^2}f(r))$$

Is it true for any radially directed function or for some specific function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Spherical_coordinates):
$$\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F} = \nabla\cdot\mathbf F = \frac1{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 F_r\right) + \frac1{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin\theta\, F_\theta) + \frac1{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial F_\varphi}{\partial \varphi}$$
Note that the terms involving the angular derivatives are zero due to the fact that the function is radially symmetric, i.e. independent of these components.

Comment: Thank you, that formula is the one I wanted to know about. Can you guide me to a proof of the formula

Comment: It's actually just a matter of applying the chain rule after changing to spherical coordinates, nothing else.I googled and the first link that popped up shows the steps https://www.cpp.edu/~ajm/materials/delsph.pdf (page 3)